# What is the necessity of calling set_current_state with TASK_RUNNING after the thread is woken up?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

As far as I understood, after a Linux Kernel thread goes to interruptible sleep, it could be woken up by two things:

1. by a wake_up family function call or
2. by a signal.

I have seen the following pattern in the kernel. I am wondering what is the necessity of calling `set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING)` at line 8? Isn't it already in `TASK_RUNNING` state right now?

```
1  set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
2  spin_lock(&list_lock);
3  if(list_empty(&list_head)) {
4         spin_unlock(&list_lock);
5         schedule();
6         spin_lock(&list_lock);
7  }
8  set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
9
10 /* Rest of the code ... */
11 spin_unlock(&list_lock);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `list_empty(&list_head)` is false it will not call `schedule()` and go to sleep. In that case it needs to set its own state back to `TASK_RUNNING` to prevent inadvertent sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

This is to avoid the lost wake-up problem. Read [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144).